# How to practice celebrations in FIFA 12

Tags: fifa-12

In FIFA 12, is there any way to practice all the different goal-scoring celebrations besides actually scoring a goal in a match?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't practice them, the only way is scoring in a match.

Answer (score 1):

Use youtube videos that show you which buttons to press for different celebrations. You can also assign specific buttons for specific celebrations from the menu so that you can customize the celebrations based on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This page has the exhaustive list to the celebrations you're looking for. It's implicit that you score a goal first

http://www.fifaencyclopedia.com/fifa-12-celebrations.php